# Django: How render two or more FBV into one template

Tags: python, django

I'd like to direct more then one view to my `file.html` template. Unfortunly my second view function `file_category` doesn't render the context in my page. Is there a specific way to do so?
Thanks

VIEWS

```
def file_view(request, file_id):  
    file = File.objects.filter(pk=file_id)
    files_p = File.objects.filter(user=request.user.userprofile)

    context = {
             'file': file,
             'files_p': files_p ,
             }
    return render(request, 'file.html', context)


def file_category(request): 
    cat = list(for num in range(0, 37)) 

    context = {
             'cat': cat
             }
    return render(request, 'file.html', context)
```

URLS

```
urlpatterns = [    
  path('show/<file_id>', views.file_view, name="file"),
  path('show/<file_id>', views.file_category),    
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have multiple views pointing to the same html template. So long as it handles the context variables properly.

For example the template doesn't require file as that isn't passed in the context on file_category view.

The issue here looks like it’s because you can’t have the same url pattern pointing to different views. How would it know which you wanted to use?

Try this:

```
path('show/<file_id>/category', views.file_category, name='file_category')
```

---

I have reproduced and fixed, here are the changes and my HTML file.

file.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    {{ file }}
    {{ files_p }}
    {{ cat }}
</body>
</html>
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('show/<file_id>', views.file_view, name="file"),
    path('show/<file_id>/category', views.file_category),
]
```

view.py

```
def file_category(request, file_id):
    cat = list(num for num in range(0, 37))

    context = {
        'cat': cat
    }
return render(request, 'file.html', context)
```

Comment: Thank you! I've tried to change the url like you suggested but nothing changed and I'm still not able to render more views in the template. Could be the problem the use of a primary key in the first function and not in the second? I've tried to add the `file = File.objects.filter(pk=file_id)` also in the second function and still doesn't work. What could be the issue?

Comment: @KomeGognome I have edited the answer with a fix, The function view was missing the file_id. and the inline loop wasn't working.

Answer (score 0):

Other than your urls being the same as Rowan said, your context on your second view only has `cat` and no `files_p` I assume you want to display file objects. So you need to pass those objects into your context on the second view, otherwise there is nothing to display. If you need to display completely different objects in your second view  then better use a different template.